# How to plot a horizontal bar chart with color defined by groups

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I'm currently struggling to set the colour by a group of the bars in a matplotlib horizontal bar chart.
I have this data frame as input:
[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIp09.png)

And so far I have this output as a graph:
[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLAne.png)

What I would like to do is to define the color of the bars according to the group and keep the bars sort by value (highest to lowest). For instance, the bars for Luc, Shan...(group A) will be shown in red, the group B in blue...

Of course, the number of groups can change (currently there is 4 groups but could be 5,6 or whatever). I also would like to add a legend.

I've tried so much to cope with this but I can't find anything on the internet about my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Pandas.plot.barh` takes a color parameter, which can be a series with colors for each table row (created using `.replace(map_group_color)`). The legend is added using matplotlib patches, which is a bit of a standard way of adding legends manually.

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

data = pd.DataFrame({"name": ["A", "B", "C"],
                     "value": [1, 5, 3],
                     "group": ["a", "a", "x"]})

data = data.sort_values("value")

map_group_color = {"a": "green", "x": "red"}
ax = data.plot.barh(x="name", y="value", 
                    color=data.group.replace(map_group_color))

legend_handles = [mpatches.Patch(color=color, label=group)
                  for group, color in map_group_color.items()]

ax.legend(handles=legend_handles)
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much. Your explanations are very clear

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for as well and worked for my use-case. Thank you!